# Blank space at the end of jasper report PDF

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to generate PDF using jasper reports, in ecplise jasper studio.      Jasper report is adding extra space at the bottom of the generated PDF. If I spread/push the contents to the bottom, space is further increasing.

See the generated PDf attached. White space is getting added at the bottom of the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ESamplePdfMainReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="39fd1111-cd7c-47f4-b044-025532f15f77">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="kitNumer" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="pageroot" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <!\[CDATA\[Query goes here\]\]>
    </queryString>

    <field name="SHIPPING_STATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <!--All fields fo here-->

    <detail>
        <band height="740" splitType="Prevent">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="10" y="324" width="181" height="162" uuid="1367c0df-6cff-446d-8889-1f553d542878"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineColor="#A6A2A2"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="59" width="180" height="112" backcolor="#F7F7F7" uuid="60816100-cb40-418e-908a-b5123ccbcb90">
                        <printWhenExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ON_FILE}.equalsIgnoreCase( "N" )\]\]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="rgba(219, 217, 217, 0.0)"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="7" y="230" width="181" height="80" uuid="68b57d02-870a-40e2-b614-964a3637ce41"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineColor="#A6A2A2"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="210" y="220" width="335" height="250" uuid="52028017-4bb4-4afa-bc16-cc98f937337c"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineColor="#A6A2A2"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="123" y="18" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFF1F0" uuid="68a8ecf4-59dd-4000-9c49-3a6bae6b826d"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#030303"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Georgia" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[SAMPLE INFORMATION\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-188" y="19" width="153" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFF1F0" uuid="f4cf1cea-528f-47d4-bf4f-1e21ccb04454"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#A6A2A2"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Georgia" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[ASSOCIATED AIRCRAFT\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-163" y="-153" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFF1F0" uuid="18293f1d-7596-49c0-adeb-f4412d2a51ad"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                        <font fontName="Georgia" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[SAMPLE TYPE\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-170" y="111" width="100" height="17" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFF1F0" uuid="0a5334fc-7d1b-433d-a22e-8f51f9eaba0c"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Georgia" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[MSP\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="19" y="291" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFF1F0" uuid="c1f17917-7492-426f-aeaa-b27c60e729ca"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Georgia" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[CUSTOMER INFORMATION\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="-201" y="-144" width="190" height="140" uuid="953bded7-6b86-4c0b-aa94-f546d9068ddd"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#A6A2A2"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="39" width="68" height="18" uuid="f99627d2-fddb-4a37-9ffd-af6e466f0d12"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Kit Serial No.:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="21" width="68" height="18" uuid="8d8c85ed-511c-4c89-9eb5-e8a5400063ff"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Sample Date:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="57" width="68" height="18" uuid="5eab4ab9-4a70-4247-b819-23c68c0c8b9c"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Sample Type:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="75" width="68" height="18" uuid="eab21a3d-a0e8-44e4-91a8-42152039080b"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Engine S.No.:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="93" width="68" height="18" uuid="eb7f22cd-7fec-4ee1-98d1-ed450b7b79e7"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Model:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="111" width="68" height="18" uuid="500d7c53-1146-4d70-bfe8-53ede7e79a40"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Type:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement x="89" y="22" width="101" height="18" uuid="4a242088-c8ac-41cf-95f8-728d69f20b75"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8.5"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy").format($F{SAMPLE_DT})\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="89" y="40" width="75" height="18" uuid="97f67f2f-e0f3-497c-ba71-61215ff0f383"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{KITNUMBER}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="89" y="76" width="75" height="18" uuid="ecf0aaa5-250f-44a2-b934-f02888b34efd"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{ENGINE_SN}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>

                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="87" y="188" width="75" height="17" uuid="3b9b0e64-201a-49a0-b01b-1c294ea5f064"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{AIRCRAFT_MODEL}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="87" y="205" width="75" height="17" uuid="99aa6bfb-3545-46fb-8dae-55f6d5a3f12a"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{AIRCRAFT_SN}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="87" y="222" width="75" height="17" uuid="6926d8c7-d143-4d38-be40-19ffd30c9910"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{AIRCRAFT_TAILNO}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="278" width="125" height="12" uuid="4bece8e5-60b7-4b4f-868e-058c3dd24616"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[KIT replacement requested:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="140" y="278" width="20" height="12" uuid="adb29efb-17bf-4379-a666-e32d7047ec8f"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{REQ_FOR_REPLACEMENT}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="11" y="290" width="125" height="12" uuid="ad934d87-77b6-4c05-8677-7250f615bcf9"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Ship to address on file:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="140" y="290" width="19" height="12" uuid="3cf05af1-cbe7-49cd-825f-1ea185639715"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="9"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ON_FILE}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="17" y="307" width="86" height="14" uuid="3ff24e07-2f4d-426c-a1e2-9ca6554ece1f">
                            <printWhenExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ON_FILE}.equalsIgnoreCase( "N" )\]\]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font isItalic="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Shipping address:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="6" y="382" width="54" height="12" uuid="d106e9cb-fa9e-4b7d-940f-fb178ffc2a98">
                            <printWhenExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{SFILE}.equalsIgnoreCase( "N" )\]\]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Postacl Code:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="7" y="393" width="54" height="12" uuid="20a892c3-ebe8-4090-bc3b-b17bdc805359">
                            <printWhenExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ON_FILE}.equalsIgnoreCase( "N" )\]\]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Mobile:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="7" y="405" width="54" height="12" uuid="f06994ce-fb95-48b2-9a2f-3b58c6d58999">
                            <printWhenExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ON_FILE}.equalsIgnoreCase( "N" )\]\]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><!\[CDATA\[Fax:\]\]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </frame>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="210" y="76" width="331" height="134" uuid="83c78a75-1b0a-418e-812c-f0109e6aedd9"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#F0F0F0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement x="9" y="188" width="321" height="154" backcolor="#F7F7F7" uuid="58b3e227-b391-4d12-a66f-d51b04883fa9"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="rgba(219, 217, 217, 0.0)"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="14" y="24" width="119" height="14" uuid="13848b31-fc95-4bad-8885-584b4d6152cd"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[TSN:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="14" y="38" width="119" height="15" uuid="529f9c76-0196-49fb-9354-3faa53f674c5"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[TSO:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="14" y="53" width="119" height="15" uuid="ffc7c7fc-596d-45d2-a832-fed9fc5ff902"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Cycles (CSN):\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="137" y="24" width="75" height="14" uuid="6156aabf-712c-457c-8644-f393af81dbc5"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{TSN}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="137" y="38" width="75" height="14" uuid="2e67c20b-5fc2-4e45-976c-e3016c1ecced"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{TSO}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="137" y="53" width="75" height="15" uuid="0e77c96e-fd8c-457e-b48a-7dd696f42474"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{CSN}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="14" y="73" width="119" height="33" uuid="4b80e2df-06af-4b97-acc7-0c68ed75556d"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Engine Operational Problems:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="136" y="73" width="186" height="24" uuid="a8f1fedc-e96d-4f77-8fda-4ffe4e16eaca"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{EOPNAMES}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="14" y="106" width="119" height="24" uuid="b48e6874-d54e-400d-93d9-5ce6ed28017b"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[If others, please specify:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="136" y="106" width="186" height="24" uuid="739efd80-41b0-4322-ab6a-c0737f6e6e35"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{EOP_OTHERS}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="7" y="184" width="113" height="18" backcolor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)" uuid="1a7b392c-5eb5-431b-a1c5-a52ea5c67b84"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom" markup="none">
                        <font size="9" isItalic="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Samudes:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="33" y="207" width="86" height="18" uuid="67ec34d7-d700-4f92-95ab-74c8d15681a1"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Filter Sample:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="33" y="235" width="86" height="18" uuid="4af45c92-d2c7-40d0-9580-41b6b5dfacd5"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Oil Sample:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="128" y="207" width="101" height="28" uuid="665b9143-adb8-4147-9cc0-f8b22010cc64"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[E Filter:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="234" y="207" width="90" height="19" uuid="61de36c0-b137-477f-8f14-6a5f9e05ec79"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{FILTER_HOURS}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="128" y="236" width="101" height="18" uuid="b421918c-f454-46f7-930e-f5863ecf8c23"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Oil Hours Since New:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="234" y="236" width="90" height="19" uuid="c2b7148b-1b0d-4ea4-b765-7c4064d06258"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[$F{OIL_HOURS}\]\]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="128" y="254" width="101" height="18" uuid="7f317de4-6d6f-4773-9fc3-24f05fe06dd7"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><!\[CDATA\[Oil Added Since Last Sample*:\]\]></text>
                </staticText>

                <reportElement x="480" y="693" width="60" height="17" uuid="72a666d7-ab81-4015-b3c4-3cd980d3852d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><!\[CDATA\[new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy").format(new Date())\]\]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="235" y="711" width="85" height="29" uuid="d0ad88a8-7349-45ea-bd7c-9e1aaa1db5f6"/>
                <imageExpression><!\[CDATA\[$P{pageroot} + "/images/o.jpg"\]\]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Please guide me to remove the space at the end.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnSlh.jpg
```

[image]